# Is Ubuntu DOD and VA IT compliant?

Tags: 16.04, server, license, legal

USA client afraid to use Ubuntu asking "Is Ubuntu DOD and VA IT compliant?"
I found that VA IT compliant but is it DOD compliant?

Comment: From https://training.linuxfoundation.org/training-bloggers/839-dod-8570-linux-certification "you can take your exam in any of the three major distribution families: Centos, OpenSUSE, and Ubuntu" although I believe RHEL is also certified. We would need more information, however, to give you a better answer.

Comment: My client needs prove of: `DoD Directive 8570.01 Certification` (Linux). Who can provide me (i cant give exam myself is there alternative way to make my systems certified by a professional to show the prove that i am compliant in-case i cant pass the exam)

Comment: If i (or my team member) get certified from https://training.linuxfoundation.org/certification  as A) system admin or B) engineer . Does that gives the approval of being ubuntu as certified : `DoD Directive 8570.01 Certification` ?

Comment: Here it says about IA certification and CA certificate to have. reference of DoD Directive 8570.01 Certification: https://www.imgva.com/8570-requirements/